# Fancybox - Overlay click, Esc and close button

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Using fancybox modal window for our application.

```
$.fancybox.open($('#fancybox-modal'));
```

to prevent user click close button, esc option and click outside close window.

But, functions inside opt is not working as expected.

Not sure which line of code is missing.

Thanks

```
$.fancybox.open({
 src: '#fancybox-modal',
 opts : {
   closeBtn  : false,
   closeClick  : false,
   helpers : { 
    overlay : {closeClick: false} 
   },
   keys : {
     close  : null
   }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `modal` option to make a *true* modal,

```
$.fancybox.open({
  src: $('#fancybox-modal'),
  type: 'inline',
  modal : true
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QeEOea?editors=1010

Tip: use `data-fancybox-close` data attribute to make any element act as close button